# Indicate hover (or tap) will show more information with many elements

Tags: tooltips, intuition, ease-of-use

First off, this is not a duplicate of the many other similar titled questions out there (that I could find at least) due to one extra bit. So please read first.

What I have is a paragraph of explanation, followed by a *long* list of references backing up the paragraph. Now, I know with things like papers, or Wikipedia, they use reference numbers, but that isn't what I'm going for.

Precisely, in my case, it's a paragraph of Biblical teaching, followed by a list of Bible passages backing it up. All of these are spelled out. Upon hovering on each one, then the full text is shown, as opposed to just the reference.

Obviously this makes the information (i) symbol not work either. The best solution I've seen so far is a dashed underline, but with so many, and with them in a long string, it seems to me that the indicator is lost (example below).

So, my question is, in this kind of scenario, is there a better option for something like this, or due to it being a situation that isn't whitespace friendly (blocks of text never are), is it just the best thing to go with?

## Example

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- **Add some structure** to the view to separate the references block more
  clearly. Use white space and font size, too. Font size helps to convey the importance of the information blocks. I suggest the references are less important.
- **Make the references more distinguishable**. Currently they look like the whole single underlined paragraph. Using the • (dot) separator allows to separate the links more clearly.
- **Convey the "there are many links" idea** by specifying the amount of the links.
- **Add signifiers to provide the better affordance**. Apply blue underlined formatting to the links.
- **Reduce visual noise** by highlighting only the "active" (under the cursor) reference section.
- **Provide a cue if needed**. Hover to show message in the reference area will work.
- **Conduct usability test** with your users
  .

[image]

Some offtopic: please pay more attention to the readability.

Comment: Fantastic. That's a million times better. I used all but the last 2 (if you drop user testing) since only one is section is visible at a time. Plus it needs to be mobile friendly, and there's no concept of hovering with mobile.

Comment: @David thank you. Mobile is a bit different story, I don't like the extensive interaction you propose for mobile.